# Looking for a book about a man building a time machine to see if Jesus was real

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

The premise of the book was as follows: a scientist creates a time machine and travels to the time of Jesus to see if he's real. Upon arriving, he finds no Jesus. He then decides to be Jesus and follows through with the work of Jesus and is crucified.

Comment: For a short story which looks at similar themes in a slightly different way, I recommend Gary Kilworth's "Let's Go To Golgotha!" -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_to_Golgotha!.

Answer (score 37):

That sounds a lot like the rather unlikable book *Behold the Man* by Michael Moorcock.  See [Behold the Man (novel), *Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behold_the_Man_(novel)).  It's a pretty good match for your description: Time machine, no Jesus, time traveler takes his place and is crucified.

Comment: Your word "unlikeable" doesn't appear precisely factual.  The Science Fiction and Fantasy Writers of America apparently liked it enough that it won a Nebula award in 1967.

Comment: Still, it's possible to unlike it …

Comment: The premise does at least _sound_ rather unlikable.  Why would anyone smart enough to build a time machine waste both it and their own life on such a stupid mission?  At least do the world a favor and kill Hitler before going back to confirm for yourself that religion is fake.

Comment: @aroth Depending on one's view of time travel, the person may not have had any choice on the matter.

Comment: The shorter version which was published in *New Worlds* is available for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_166v50_1966-09). I didn't like it either, never bothered to read the book length version.

Comment: @aroth attitudes were *much* different 50 years ago.

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly sure that this brief description is incorrect in one respect. There *is* a Jesus, he's just mentally subnormal or something. Moorcock trying to up the blasphemy/shock quotient, presumably.

Comment: @aroth http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HitlersTimeTravelExemptionAct

Comment: Technically he doesn't find "no Jesus", but I won't spoil it for people.

Comment: @aroth what makes you think killing Hitler would have any appreciable effect on modern history?  You would have to take out dozens of people in the same leadership to accomplish anything more than a minor hiccup in our timeline there...

Comment: “unlikable” or ‘dislikable’?

Comment: Behold the man may be the book I was thinking of. I don't quite remember it the way it's described though. I will check it out to see if it's the right book. I thought the one I'm looking for was written in the eighties. I could be wrong. I read the book in '87 or '88.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the book! Thanks! I found it on Amazon and the cover is definitely the one I remembered. https://www.amazon.com/Behold-Man-Michael-Moorcock/dp/0380399822/ref=tmm_mmp_title_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=

Comment: @TripeHound Jokes on you Hitler didn't kill himself, he went back in time to become Jesus, now that's your job!

Answer (score 3):

Possibly  you are thinking of "The Didymus Contingency" by Jeremy Robinson.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/514140.The_Didymus_Contingency

> If you could go back in time...and witness any event...where would
>   you go?
>
> When Dr. Tom Greenbaum faces that question after successfully
>   discovering the secret to time travel, he knows the time, place and
>   event he will witness: the death and failed resurrection of Jesus
>   Christ.

Comment: There are a hundred stories about time travellers at the crucifixion. The OP is asking about a story where the time traveller takes over the role of Jesus, and is crucified. If that happens in "The Didymus Contingency" you need to spell it out.

Answer (score 1):

The plot seems to be quite similar to this one:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caballo_de_Troya

> The plot of the book unveils the last period in the life of Jesus Christ as revealed through the first-hand experience of two pilots (or rather "timenauts"), members of a US Air Force top-secret military experimental project on time travel codenamed "Operation Trojan Horse", who in 1973 supposedly succeeded in travelling back in time to the land of Palestine in the year 30 A.d.

Comment: The Wikipedia summary of "Trojan Horse" does not indicate that the time travellers played the role of Jesus. (If they did, you should add that to your answer.) Therefore, it seems to me that it does not match the OP's description any better than all the other stories about time travellers going back to see Jesus.